# Accessing page objects through static methods

Tags: c#, jquery, datepicker, static-methods

I am using asp.net datepicker.  Then executing a static event when a user clicks on a date through jquery like such:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("#<%= lblDate.ClientID %>").text("Are available on " + $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val());

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Schedule.aspx/DisplayAvail",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        // Do something interesting here.
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod] 
    public static void DisplayAvail()
    {
         //Grab data from db to check avail from this date
    }
```

Which works fine.  But, from this static method there is no way to access page level objects.  How can I send data from this method to the page?

Comment: you will have to use JSON. Have a look at Json.Net

Comment: tranceporter has the code for "get stuff from DB via AJAX and display it", but this is a key point about ASP.NET: between page loads and postbacks _there is no page object_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the best rout to go is to use JQuery load() function to load an external page into the current page as such:

...Jquery

```
$("#GetData").load("getData.aspx?GetDate=012420012");
```

...html

```
<div id="GetData">
...
</div>
```

Thanks for all your feedback, but I think that this is the best way to go.  Cheers!  :)

Comment: Or more specifically, (For those that might find this page later) I used JQuery to grab the date from the page object:
  
`$("#GetData").load("getData.aspx?Date=" + $("#myDate"));`


You also do not have to load all the html tags like body and form and what not since JQuery just inserts the html markup in to where you specify.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here. You can get this via NuGet

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Once you have the NewtonSoft Json dll added as a reference to your project which contains the webmethod, you can use JSONConvert to serialize your available dates and send it client side.

```
public IEnumerable<string> AvailableData {get; set;}

[WebMethod] 
    public static void DisplayAvail()
    {
        this.AvailableData = GetRequiredData();
        this.AvailableData = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(this.AvailableData);
    }
```

And on the client side, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("#<%= lblDate.ClientID %>").text("Are available on " + $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Schedule.aspx/DisplayAvail",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                        var arr = <%= this.AvailableData %>;
                       $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
                            // Do something with the data
                       });

                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But I dont want to install third party dll's.  Want to figure this out just using the existing framework.  I am surprised that there is nothing else besides NewtonSoft's Json dll.

Comment: If you do not want to use JSON, then you will have to convert result from GetRequiredData to string, assign it to AvailableData, and parse/split/process it on client side using jQuery. The problem is that you want an array shared on client side. If it were a string, it would be a simple matter of assigning it to AvailableData and using it on client side.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using PageMethods():

This is a simple tutorial [Simple PageMethods example.](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

And also you need to do this:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

;)

Comment: This method goes from an Instance method to a static method.  The issue I am have that when the jquery executes, you have to execute a static method that does not have access to the instance methods and page objects.  Hhhmm....